# Extracting all hex values from HTML / CSS using PHP

Tags: php, html, css, parsing

I want to echo out all the hex values used on a webpage using PHP. I know it's possible to parse HTML, but I don't know how to also parse the relevant CSS.

For example; If I had a webpage like so

```css
body {
  background-color: #F77A52;
}
h1 {
  color: #2577C2;
  background-color: #FF6A00;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-gb">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Title Page</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <h1 class="text-center">Hello World</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

I would like the PHP to output something like:

> body: #F77A52
>
> h1: #2577C2, #FF6A00

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://github.com/kennwilson/colormap-php/blob/master/colormap.php) might be of help for you

It has been extracted from [Hextractor](https://hex.corvidworks.com/)

Comment: This just seems to convert Hex to RGB and so fourth. I'm looking to get the code that extracts the hex values from a webpage.

Comment: if you copy and paste a css in Hextractor, it automatically understands the colors. You can try to have a look at their source code to get some tips

Comment: Their source code doesn't seem to have anything helpful in it. If it was done in PHP I won't be able to see it.